# Root node of TreeView gets copied

Tags: vb.net, treeview, treenode

I have the following problem. I'm going through a TreeView to fill an XML-tree with the items that are checked in my TreeView. Basically everything works fine, except that every time I finish filling the XML-tree, I get a copy of my TreeView-rootnode inside the TreeView.

Strange thing is, the new node behaves like a ghost of the first one. I can't check/uncheck checkboxes, but the corresponding boxes in the original node are checked/unchecked. But I am able to expand or collapse the nodes of the ghost.

The count of my TreeView.Nodes also stays at 1, so deleting the ghost is not possible, since it's not there. I also tried refreshing the TreeView, but there was no change. Even clearing the TreeView doesn't get rid of the ghost (clearing also is not a preferred option ;)).

Here's the relevant pieces of code:

```
Private Sub btnSaveReport_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveReport.Click
    Dim newXML As XDocument = XDocument.Load("some.xml")
    Dim xmlTree As XElement = newXML.Root
    buildReportTree(trvMyTree.Nodes(0), xmlTree)
    Console.WriteLine(xmlTree)
End Sub

Private Sub buildReportTree(ByRef treeNode As TreeNode, ByRef currentElement As XElement)
    If treeNode.Checked Then
        Dim newNode As XElement
        newNode = buildReportNode(treeNode)
        currentElement.Add(newNode)
        For Each childNode As TreeNode In treeNode.Nodes
            buildReportTree(childNode, newNode)
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Function buildReportNode(treeNode As TreeNode) As XElement
    If treeNode.ToolTipText = "property" Then
        Dim newNode As XElement = New XElement(treeNode.ToolTipText, treeNode.Name)
        Return newNode
    End If
    If treeNode.ToolTipText = "collection" Or treeNode.ToolTipText = "reference" Then
        Dim newNode As XElement = New XElement(treeNode.ToolTipText, _
                                  New XAttribute("name", treeNode.Name))
        Return newNode
    End If
    Return Nothing ' ToDo: handle errors
End Function
```

Once the first call of buildReportTree is finished, the ghost appears. Any ideas what the problem could be? Maybe I just haven't found the right search terms yet, but so far I didn't find any answers to this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi everyone, I found the answer (correct search term was "phantom"): The root node has to be assigned to a variable, then it works. As the original poster, I have no idea why. Here's the original forum post I found: [Phantom Nodes](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?654970-RESOLVED-Phantom-nodes-in-a-treeview)

Comment: can you share xml files used in above code example?

Comment: You should write up what you found, and accept it as the answer, so we can upvote it!

Answer (score 1):

[From the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826069/root-node-of-treeview-gets-copied#comment19046620_13826069):

> Hi everyone, I found the answer (correct search term was "phantom"): The root node has to be assigned to a variable, then it works. As the original poster, I have no idea why. Here's the original forum post I found: [Phantom Nodes](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?654970-RESOLVED-Phantom-nodes-in-a-treeview)